# Regex that matches href="" in an <a> tag

Tags: regex, phpmyadmin

I would like to replace all `href=""` links within the `<a>` tags. But I need the expression to ignore everything else inside the tag, like `class=""` and `target=""`.
Example:

```
    <a target="_blank" class="col-md-6" href="link.com">
    <a href="link.com" class="col-md-6" target="_blank">
```

I ended up getting this expression:`<a[^>]*\K(href=".*?")`
I'm using phpmyadmin and unfortunately it doesn't recognize the \K reference.

Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: The ">" was just to show the part to be extracted. Anyway, html ajusted

Comment: OK, one last question, what is the desired output?  You mentioned that you want to replace the `href` values, but you did not say with what.

Comment: You can try using multiple capturing groups, something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/yv3M4a/1).

Comment: Hey Tim. I want to replace it with a function: `onclick = "parent.document.getElementById('btn_copy'). Click ()"`

Comment: What exactly does it mean that phpMyAdmin doesn't recognize `\K` ? Is there an error? It seems to work as expected for me, using PHP 8.1 and phpMyAdmin 5.1. Which phpMyAdmin and PHP versions are you using?

Answer (score -1):

```
<aside href="link.com">
<a target="_blank" class="col-md-6" href="link.com">
<a > href="link.com" class="col-md-6" target="_blank">
<a > href="link.com" class="col-md-6" target="_blank">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).